# How to pass argument from npm script to lerna command

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-scripts, lerna

I am looking to pass `stage` argument from `npm` script to `lerna` which will call `npm` script in each of the packages.

Here's what it looks like:

In deploy.sh, I run:

```
npm run deploy:cicd  -- --stage dev
```

In package.json, I have:

```
"deploy:cicd": " lerna run deploy --stream",
```

In each of the packages, the deploy script looks like this:

```
"deploy": "sls deploy -v",
```

I need to be able to pass the `stage` name from `deploy.sh`  so that the deploy command executed in each of the packages will be :

```
"sls deploy -v --stage dev ",
```

Currently, I get an error:

```
> lerna run deploy --stream "-stage" "dev"

ERR! lerna Unknown arguments: p, r, o, f, i, l, e
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /codebuild/output/src202136904/src
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c  lerna run deploy --stream "-stage" "dev"
```

In deploy.sh, I tried passing

```
npm run deploy:cicd  -- -- -stage dev
```

and

```
npm run deploy:cicd  -- -stage dev
```

and

```
npm run deploy:cicd  -- stage dev
```

Neither of these has worked for me.

Comment: So, in _deploy.sh_ you run `npm run deploy:cicd  -- --stage dev` _(note your `--stage` argument begins with two hyphens)_, however in the error you got it states `lerna run deploy --stream "-stage" "dev"` _(note `-stage` now begins with one hyphen)_ - that does seems odd? Is that a typo?

Comment: Typo yes. I tried a couple of things and neither worked.  @RobC

Comment: Could you please provide some of your `package.json`s scripts sections? Otherwise it's not really clear on which level are you doing what

Comment: any solution found?

Comment: I used 3 pairs of hyphens and that worked @RobBoerman